# Loopback 4 cli instructions language - how to reset

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I am trying to create a new project in LoopBack 4 CLI using `lb4` but the language it pops up such as project name and directory is in Turkish language.

How do I reset or change the LoopBack 4 CLI language?

Comment: Using lb4 not lp4

Answer (score 0):

No worries, it us back to English after a fresh install